# Small chat program, access variables between files

Tags: java

at the moment I am creating a simple chat program that will allow you to communicate between a server. I am having an issue accessing the username variable when it is used in one file in another file. The user will enter his name, this is done in the ChatGUI file, then when he enters the chat room a EchoFrame is created, which is in the EchoFrame file. Also in the EchoFrame file, I want to append the username to the users message, and also announce when they connect to the chatroom and when they leave the chat room. I hope I was clear on explaining my issue, any other information needed please let me know!

EchoFrame

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class EchoFrame extends Frame{

    EchoPanel ep;
    Button sendMessage;

    public EchoFrame(){

        setSize(500,500);
        setTitle("Echo Client");
        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter(){
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent we){
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

        ep = new EchoPanel();
        add(ep, BorderLayout.CENTER);




        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        EchoFrame ef = new EchoFrame();

    }
}


class EchoPanel extends Panel implements ActionListener, Runnable{

    TextField tf;
    TextArea ta;
    Button connect, disconnect;
    Socket s;
    BufferedReader br;
    PrintWriter pw;
    Thread t;
    String fromServer;
    String username;


    public EchoPanel(){

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        tf = new TextField();
        tf.setEditable(false);
        tf.addActionListener(this);
        add(tf, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        ta = new TextArea();
        ta.setEditable(false);
        add(ta, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        Panel buttonPanel = new Panel();
        connect = new Button("Connect");
        connect.addActionListener(this);
        buttonPanel.add(connect);
        disconnect = new Button("Disconnect");
        disconnect.setEnabled(false);
        disconnect.addActionListener(this);
        buttonPanel.add(disconnect);
        add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);



    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){

        if(ae.getSource() == connect){
            try{
                s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 8189);
                ta.append(username + " has entered the chat room. \n");
                br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
                pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
            }catch(UnknownHostException uhe){
                System.out.println(uhe.getMessage());
            }catch(IOException ioe){
                System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
            }

            t = new Thread(this);
            t.start();
            tf.setEditable(true);
            connect.setEnabled(false);
            disconnect.setEnabled(true);
        }else if(ae.getSource() == disconnect){
            try{
                pw.close();
                br.close();
                s.close();
            }catch(IOException ioe){
                System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
            }
            t = null;
            ta.append(username + " has disconnected from chat room. \n");
            tf.setEditable(false);
            connect.setEnabled(true);
            disconnect.setEnabled(false);
        }else if(ae.getSource() == tf){
            String fromTf = tf.getText();
            pw.println(fromTf);
            tf.setText("");

        }else{

                //additional events
        }
    }

    public void run (){
        fromServer = "";
        try{
            while((fromServer = br.readLine()) != null){

                    ta.append(username + ":" + fromServer + "\n");
            }   
        }catch(IOException ioe){
            System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

ChatGUI

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;




public class ChatGUI extends JFrame {

    private int currentCard = 1;
    private JPanel cardPanel;
    private CardLayout cl;
    JTextField usernameField;
    String username;

    public ChatGUI() {

        setTitle("Chat Program");
        setSize(500, 120);
        cardPanel = new JPanel();

        cl = new CardLayout();
        cardPanel.setLayout(cl);

        JPanel chooseUsername = new JPanel();
        JLabel usernameLabel = new JLabel("Please enter your username:");

        chooseUsername.add(usernameLabel);
        cardPanel.add(chooseUsername, "Log in");

        usernameField = new JTextField(15);


        usernameField.setEditable(true);
        add(usernameField, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        JButton logInBtn = new JButton("Enter Chat Room");

        buttonPanel.add(logInBtn);



        logInBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                currentCard = 2;
                cl.show(cardPanel, "" + (currentCard));

                username = usernameField.getText();  //gets username
                EchoFrame ef = new EchoFrame();    //creates message room

            }
        });


        getContentPane().add(cardPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        getContentPane().add(buttonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ChatGUI cl = new ChatGUI();
        cl.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        cl.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Chat Server

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ChatServer{
    Socket s;
    ArrayList <ChatHandler>handlers;
    public ChatServer(){
        try{
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(8189);
            handlers = new ArrayList<ChatHandler>();
            for(;;){
                s = ss.accept();
                new ChatHandler(s, handlers).start();
            }
        }catch(IOException ioe){
            System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ChatServer tes = new ChatServer(); 
    }
}
```

Chat Handler

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;

public class ChatHandler extends Thread{
    Socket s;
    BufferedReader br;
    PrintWriter pw;
    String temp;
    ArrayList <ChatHandler>handlers;

    public ChatHandler(Socket s, ArrayList <ChatHandler>handlers){
        this.s = s;
        this.handlers = handlers;
    }


    public void run(){
        try{
            handlers.add(this);
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream(), true);
            temp = "";
            while((temp = br.readLine()) != null){
                for (ChatHandler ch : handlers){
                    ch.pw.println(temp); 
                }
                System.out.println(temp);
            }
        }catch(IOException ioe){
            System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());      
        }finally{
            handlers.remove(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

Make `userName` static and access it via `ChatUI.userName`. In actuality, `userName` shouldn't be in `ChatUI`. Alternatively, a more heavyweight option would be to get MySQL, set up a database, and connect to it via [JDBC](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/), if you're going to have more than one user.

You can also try and follow from these examples: [Simple Client And Server Chat Program](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/262304-simple-client-and-server-chat-program/) and [Creating a simple Chat Client/Server Solution](http://pirate.shu.edu/~wachsmut/Teaching/CSAS2214/Virtual/Lectures/chat-client-server.html). They cover key topics, such as multithreading.

Comment: Hmm I ran into a problem, it worked but in the chat GUI it doesn't show each name when there are two GUIS open. For example if Ross and Bob were chatting it would just look like Ross is the only one talking on his screen

Comment: You can try and follow from these examples: [Simple Client And Server Chat Program](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/262304-simple-client-and-server-chat-program/) and  [Creating a simple Chat Client/Server Solution](http://pirate.shu.edu/~wachsmut/Teaching/CSAS2214/Virtual/Lectures/chat-client-server.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a server program and a client program, so all variables you need to send to each client can be into the server.

When a client conect to the server a you add that client(username,ipadress,whatever) to a list of connected clients and create a new thread to listen/send to that client. then from the server you can send to all users(threads) the Username and what he wrote if u have a function sendToAll(idThreadSender, threadX.text) or you can sendtothread(threadX,threadY.text) well i think you have a bad structure, thats all.

hope i helped.

Comment: This make sense, if only I knew how to do it :o